# k and r line counting 1.5.3 not working?

Tags: c, getchar

I'm having trouble with k&r 1.5.3. Obviously I'm a complete beginner. Below is the code exactly from the book and exactly as I typed it. It compiled fine and runs. It returns characters but just never prints the line count. I'm using ssh into a Ubuntu machine. Can the  key on my wife's mac not be interpreted as '\n'?

```
#include <stdio.h>

/*count lines in input*/

main()
{
     int c, n1;

     n1 = 0;
     while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
          if (c == '\n')
               ++n1;
     printf("%d\n", n1);
}
```

Comment: Is that on OS X or Mac OS 9?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Correct. Mac uses `\r` as line ending: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline

Update your code like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/*count lines in input*/

main()
{
     int c, n1;

     n1 = 0;
     while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
          if (c == '\r')                      /* use \r for Macs */
               ++n1;
     printf("%d\n", n1);
}
```

**However**

When I try to do the same, I have to `Ctrl-D` to enter an `EOF` and trigger the program to print the line count.

Comment: Wouldn't the `\r` be translated to `\n` on input, just as `\n` is translated to `\r` on output? Or is `stdin` opened in binary mode?

Comment: @wRAR, yes this only applies to MAC OS 9.

Comment: @FredLarson AFAIK, `stdin` is not translated.